# Creating a Visual Studio project from command line or powershell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

I have a quite huge solution and I've to perform some maintenance (creating test classes for whole projects and so on) and I was wondering if it's possible with powershell or vscode to create projects automatically. I've just followed [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1922664.aspx?Using%20Command%20Prompt%20to%20create%20a%20visual%20studio%20projects%20and%20Solutions%20files) link and tried to use the [IVSSolution interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017) from powershell but with no luck. Is there a working and simplier solution?

Comment: New projects can be created via `dotnet new` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x but it relies on .NET Core SDK installation.

Comment: I know but this only applies to .NET Core projects... I need for .NET Framework

Comment: @advapi have you find out how to create a project from the command line? I need it as well.

Answer (score 0):

While, I'm not sure your requirements, I think what you should be really looking for is [Project Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx).

[This blog](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/creating-visual-studio-project-templates-and-item-templates/) explains the process of creating a project template in details. Or, You can, create a project template using [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462544/powershell-script-to-create-visual-studio-project-template-extension-zip-issue).

Comment: No, I don't need to create a project template.... I just want to create a new .NET Framework project... from command line!